# SQL Performance UNION vs OR

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, union

I just read part of an optimization article and *segfaulted* on the following statement:

> When using SQL replace statements using `OR` with a `UNION`:
>
> ```
> select username from users where company = ‘bbc’ or company = ‘itv’;
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> select username from users where company = ‘bbc’ union
> select username from users where company = ‘itv’;
> ```

From a quick `EXPLAIN`:

Using `OR`:

[image]

Using `UNION`:

[image]

Doesn't this mean `UNION` does in *double the work*?

While I appreciate `UNION` may be more performant for certain RDBMSes and certain table schemas, this is not *categorically true* as the author suggestions.

#### Question

Am I wrong?

Comment: I would think that `UNION` is doing more work as it needs to remove the duplicates, where the filter would fetch the specified criteria. I'm surprised that it doesn't recommend using `IN`.

Comment: It can be true, if mysql cant use indexes when there is `OR` in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Igor Romanchenko, support this with an answer.

Comment: I would guess that the query analyzer would re-write the or statements into an IN statement, since they are equivalent

Comment: @Darren Kopp, I'm pretty sure it's the other way around. At least in MySQL anyway.

Comment: We use DB2 and interestingly enough, our DBAs had us rewrite OR statements with UNION statements because the explain came out better.  I'm uncertain if this is always the case though as we have OR statements in other places that explain out fine.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Either the article you read used a bad example, or you misinterpreted their point.

```
select username from users where company = 'bbc' or company = 'itv';
```

This is equivalent to:

```
select username from users where company IN ('bbc', 'itv');
```

MySQL can use an index on `company` for this query just fine.  There's no need to do any UNION.

The more tricky case is where you have an `OR` condition that involves two *different* columns.

```
select username from users where company = 'bbc' or city = 'London';
```

Suppose there's an index on `company` and a separate index on `city`.  Given that MySQL usually uses only one index per table in a given query, which index should it use?  If it uses the index on `company`, it would still have to do a table-scan to find rows where `city` is London.  If it uses the index on `city`, it would have to do a table-scan for rows where `company` is bbc.

The `UNION` solution is for this type of case.

```
select username from users where company = 'bbc' 
union
select username from users where city = 'London';
```

Now each sub-query can use the index for its search, and the results of the subquery are combined by the `UNION`.

An anonymous user proposed an edit to my answer above, but a moderator rejected the edit. It should have been a comment, not an edit. The claim of the proposed edit was that UNION has to sort the result set to eliminate duplicate rows. This makes the query run slower, and the index optimization is therefore a wash.

UNION does have to eliminate duplicates, and to do that it sorts the result set, so there is some overhead. But it usually only has to sort a small result set.

There might be cases where the WHERE clauses match a significant portion of the table, and sorting during UNION is as expensive as simply doing the table-scan. But it's more common for the result set to be reduced by the indexed searches, so the sorting of a small set of rows is much less costly than the table-scan of a large set of rows.

The difference depends on the data in the table, and the terms being searched. The only way to determine the best solution for a given query is to try both methods in the MySQL query profiler and compare their performance.

Comment: The quote I provided was the exact example in the article. So there was nothing to misinterpretation. I knew using `UNION` vs. `OR` was **not categorically true**. But I am marking this as correct since it addressed the original example as *incorrect*, while providing a use case of what the author likely *meant*.

Comment: Alas, the author may have been writing about a solution without understanding the cases where the solution is useful versus not needed.  Or he may have been basing his knowledge on an ancient version of MySQL that didn't optimize `IN()` predicates as well.

Comment: @BillKarwin if the two different columns are indexed then won't MySQL perform "Index Merge Optimization" to get merged result of individual scans based on both the two indexes?

Comment: @sactiw, Sometimes. In practice, I have found that the optimizer doesn't use the index merge when one would expect it to, so I don't rely on this.

Comment: I finally understand the need for UNION.  Thanks!  I am ordering your book from Amazon.

Comment: If the two columns in the WHERE clause came from different tables, would that negate the need to rewrite the query using UNION?  If it's `tbl1.company = 'bbc' OR tbl2.city = 'london'` can MySQL make full use of indexes, since it can have one index per table?

Comment: Try it out with EXPLAIN and see!

Comment: Just curiosity, the article is now old, but was it from w3schools by any chance...

Comment: I have no idea, the OP did not post a link. I google for the phrase the OP is quoting, but I don't find it.

Comment: This explains alot, specially query times when in the Where clause it is validating columns from one Join OR another column from another Join. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Those are not the same query.

I don't have much experience with MySQL, so I am not sure what the query optimizer does or does not do, but here are my thoughts from my general background (primarily ms sql server).

Typically, the query analyzer can take the above two queries and make the exact same plan out of them (if they were the same), so it wouldn't matter. I would suspect that there is no performance difference between these queries (which are equivalent)

```
select distinct username from users where company = ‘bbc’ or company = ‘itv’;
```

and

```
select username from users where company = ‘bbc’ 
union
select username from users where company = ‘itv’;
```

Now, the question is, would there be a difference between the following queries, of which I actually don't know, but I would suspect that the optimizer would make it more like the first query

```
select username from users where company = ‘bbc’ or company = ‘itv’;
```

and

```
select username from users where company = ‘bbc’ 
union all
select username from users where company = ‘itv’;
```

Comment: + about the queries not being the same. Nonetheless, `UNION ALL` still yields the same `EXPLAIN` as `UNION`.

Comment: `UNION ALL` is usually faster than `UNION`.  The latter implies `UNION DISTINCT`, thereby requiring a de-dup pass over a temp table.  Newer versions avoid the temp table in certain situations, thereby helping more.    The `or` example you have is always faster, because it can use `INDEX(company)`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the optimizer ends up doing based on the size of the data, indexes, software version, etc.

I would guess that using OR would give the optimizer a better chance at finding some efficiencies, since everything is in a single logical statement.

Also, UNION has some overhead, since it creates a reset *set* (no duplicates).
Each statement in the UNION should execute pretty quickly if *company* is indexed... not sure it'd really be doing *double* the work.

#### Bottom line

Unless you really have a burning need to squeeze every bit of speed out of your query, it's probably better to just go with the form that best communicates your intention... the OR

#### Update

I also meant to mention IN. I believe the following query will give better performance than the OR (it's also the form I prefer):

`select username from users where company in ('bbc', 'itv');`

Answer (score 0):

**This my benchmark result**

---

> When use UNION  -   Query took `13.8699` seconds
> row examined primary select type  - `247685`
>
> when use OR     -   Query took `0.0126` seconds and  row examined primary
> select type    - `495371`

MySQL uses one index for a query, so when we are using `or` then mysql use one column index and scan full table for another column

another part union same work can 2 times

that's why or is faster then union

Comment: It would help if you showed your code.  And also how many times did you repeat the experiment.

Answer (score -1):

In almost all cases, the `union` or `union all` version is going to do two full table scans of the users table.

The `or` version is much better in practice, since it will only scan the table once.  It will also use an index only once, if available.

The original statement just seems wrong, for just about any database and any situation.

Comment: Just to be clear, `UNION` will also use an index if available. But it will scan both *tables*. Just a smaller dataset then merge them back together.

Comment: no-no-no, if you use `or`/`in` you are going to use "index range scan", and in the case of `union`/`union all` you are going to use `non-unique` or even `primary key lookup` plus `index merge`

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev . . . The explain results are quite clear that there are no indexes on the table.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Question does not state a condition of "no indexes on the table" as well as you answer. If you would put this at the start of your answer it would help people like me to look for their case scenarios.

Comment: `IN` and `OR` are the same.  You can see this by getting the `EXPLAIN` to see that the Optimizer turns one into the other.

Answer (score -1):

Bill Karwin's answer is pretty right. When the both part of the OR statement has its own index, it's better doing union because once you have a small subset of results, it's easier to sort them and eliminate duplicates. Total cost is almost less than using only one index (for one of the column) and table scan for the other column (because mysql only uses one index for one column).

It depends of the table's structure and needs generally but in large tables union gave to me better results.

Comment: you said `mysql only uses one index for one column` - it is not true. You can have your column in many indexes.

Comment: During execution of a query, mysql uses only one index for a single column. It is not about ability to define multiple indexes on one column.

Comment: This is not true again. MySQL uses one index for a query, not for one column.

Comment: Let's phrase it even more precisely:  "one index per `SELECT`".  (This avoids the ambiguity of whether a `UNION` is one or multiple "query".)

Comment: @RickJames I say, "one index per table reference" because in a query with joins, each table reference may use an index. Even when doing self-joins, each table reference to the same table might use a different index.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Good point.