# Can this sql with 2 unions be minimized to no unions?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, union

I have a query that I use 2 UNIONS to get the results that I need

It may be done using a CASE statement but I could not figure it out. I will appreciated it if some can can solve this problem

This is my current query please keep in mind that viewable_by can be only 1, 2 or 3 However, client_id, team_id and created_by will be a variable depending on the user those will change

```
SELECT view_name, view_id, viewable_by  FROM `phone_call_views`
WHERE status = 1 AND ( viewable_by = 1  AND client_id = 1)
UNION
SELECT view_name, view_id, viewable_by  FROM `phone_call_views`
WHERE status = 1 AND ( viewable_by = 2  AND team_id =5 AND client_id = 1)
UNION
SELECT view_name, view_id, viewable_by  FROM `phone_call_views`
WHERE status = 1 AND ( viewable_by = 3  AND created_by= 6)
```

This is my actual query with the variable in php

```
$db->getDataSet(' SELECT view_name, view_id, viewable_by  FROM `phone_call_views`
                                     WHERE status = 1 AND ( viewable_by = 1  AND client_id = '.CLIENT_ID.')
                                     UNION
                                     SELECT view_name, view_id, viewable_by  FROM `phone_call_views`
                                     WHERE status = 1 AND ( viewable_by = 2  AND team_id ='.TEAM_ID.' AND client_id = '.CLIENT_ID.')
                                     UNION
                                     SELECT view_name, view_id, viewable_by  FROM `phone_call_views`
                                     WHERE status = 1 AND ( viewable_by = 3  AND created_by= '.USER_ID.') '
                                    );
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use UNION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them like this:

```
SELECT view_name, view_id, viewable_by  FROM `phone_call_views`
WHERE status = 1 AND (
   (viewable_by = 1  AND client_id = 1) or 
   (viewable_by = 2  AND team_id =5 AND client_id = 1) or 
   (viewable_by = 3  AND created_by= 6)
)
```

You can also use **`SELECT .... WHERE IN`** statement to combine the OR statements.

Like

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE viewable_by IN (1,2,3)
```

Will translate to

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE viewable_by='1' or viewable_by='2' or viewable_by='3'
```

But `IN` clauses I believe while logically equivalent to `OR`'s are not at all the same when it comes to query execution

Comment: IN clauses I believe while logically equivalent to OR's are not at all the same when it comes to query execution.

Comment: @DanielWilliams, Very true. I should have added this to the answer.

Comment: Agree with Daniel Williams. No way you could convert this query to using IN and still maintain the AND conditions separated by each OR.

Comment: @MikePurcell, I never said it could :)

Comment: "You can also use SELECT .... WHERE IN statement to combine the OR statements."

Comment: @MikePurcell, Yes Mike, `to combine the OR Statements` that does not mean, combine the `OR` statement and `AND` statement as in the questions. My last edit should fix this confusion though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT view_name, view_id, viewable_by  FROM `phone_call_views`
WHERE status = 1 AND ( (viewable_by = 1  AND client_id = 1) OR 
( viewable_by = 2  AND team_id =5 AND client_id = 1) OR ( viewable_by = 3  AND created_by= 6))
```

Is the easiest way to do it

Also, with mysql, remember that UNION will remove duplicates and this will not.

If you can limit your logical constraints to the same set of columns for each query you can replace all the OR's and UNION's with WHERE ROW(all your columns) IN (all your values). But given that you have very different requirements per query, I think the OR's are your best bet.

Comment: ORs are nasty and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Having worked with them many moons ago, we found them to be non-performant and hard to optimize.

Comment: @MikePurcell, How can an operator be non-performant? And why would you want to optimize `OR`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be so abstract with my previous comment. I just remember that when we were working to reduce our Queries Per Second (qps), several of the 'slow' queries (>2s) included ors. I'm sure a DBA can explain in more detail, but this is a good read too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750475/sql-performance-union-vs-or

Comment: @MikePurcell, I am sure Or is a lot better than having 2 unions

Comment: @MikePurcell, Looking at the situation, I dont see any other way to solves this problem without the `UNION`.

Comment: @Starx: If the OP wants to move away from Unions, I agree. Just curious why he doesn't want to use Union.