# Multiple indexes vs single index on multiple columns in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

I could not reach any conclusive answers reading some of the existing posts on this topic.

I have certain data at 100 locations the for past 10 years. The table has about 800 million rows. I need to primarily generate yearly statistics for each location. Some times I need to generate monthly variation statistics and hourly variation statistics as well. I'm wondering if I should generate two indexes - one for location and another for year or generate one index on both location and year. My primary key currently is a serial number (Probably I could use location and timestamp as the primary key).

Thanks.

Comment: Contrast explained with analogy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24315527/7750999

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Regardless of how many indices have you created on relation, only one of them will be used in a certain query (which one depends on query, statistics etc). So in your case you wouldn't get a cumulative advantage from creating two single column indices. To get most performance from index I would suggest to use composite index on (location, timestamp).

Note, that queries like `... WHERE timestamp BETWEEN smth AND smth` will not use the index above while queries like `... WHERE location = 'smth'` or `... WHERE location = 'smth' AND timestamp BETWEEN smth AND smth` will. It's because the first attribute in index is crucial for searching and sorting.

Don't forget to perform

```
ANALYZE;
```

after index creation in order to collect statistics.

**Update:**
As **@MondKin** mentioned in comments certain queries can actually use several indexes on the same relation. For example, query with `OR` clauses like `a = 123 OR b = 456` (assuming that there are indexes for both columns). In this case postgres would perform bitmap index scans for both indexes, build a union of resulting bitmaps and use it for bitmap heap scan. In certain conditions the same scheme may be used for `AND` queries but instead of union there would be an intersection.

Comment: About `only one of them will be used in a certain query` actually Postgres does have the ability to use multiple indexes to satisfy a single query. Check this chapter in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html Specifically `Fortunately, PostgreSQL has the ability to combine multiple indexes`

Comment: What if I have multicolumn B-tree index `(location, timestamp)`, and I use one of them in `where` closure. For example `where location = smth` or `timestamp = smth` will the index I have created work?

Comment: awesome answer!

Comment: @Mukhammadsher Very late reply, but postgres can use the compound index to lookup for the first column only. The `(location, timestamp)` index can be used to query `location`, but not to query only `timestamp`.

Answer (score 13):

There is no rule of thumb for situations like these, I suggest you experiment in a copy of your production DB to see what works best for you: a single multi-column index or 2 single-column indexes.

One nice feature of Postgres is you can have multiple indexes and use them in the same query. Check [this chapter of the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html):

> ... PostgreSQL has the ability to combine multiple indexes ... to handle cases that cannot be implemented by single index scans ....
>
> ... Sometimes multicolumn indexes are best, but sometimes it's better to create separate indexes and rely on the index-combination feature ...

You can even experiment creating both the individual and combined indexes, and checking [how big each one is](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) and determine if it's worth having them at the same time.

Some things that you can also experiment with:

- If your table is too large, consider [partitioning it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html). It looks like you could partition either by location or by date. Partitioning splits your table's data in smaller tables, reducing the amount of places where a query needs to look.
- If your data is laid out according to a date (like transaction date) check [BRIN indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/brin-intro.html).
- If multiple queries will be processing your data in a similar fashion (like aggregating all transactions over the same period, check [materialized views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) so you only need to do those costly aggregations once.

About the order in which to put your multi-column index, put first the column on which you will have an equality operation, and later the column in which you have a range, `>=` or `<=` operation.

Answer (score 2):

An index on (location,timestamp) should work better that 2 separate indexes for you case. Note that the order of the columns is important.

Comment: Thank you. How does the order of the columns effects performance?

Comment: If your search criteria is like `location="something" AND timestamp BETWEEN something AND something`, then an index on `(location,timestamp)` can be used for that, whereas an index on `(timestamp,location)` could not.

Comment: Not true. Order of where conditions is not important at all. See here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115759

Comment: @T3rm1 I am referring to the order of columns in the definition of a multicolumn index. This is totally different than what your link is about, which is about the order of conditions in a `WHERE` clause. In the former case the order matters, in the latter it doesn't.