# MYSQL best use of indexes for a JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

`homes_info` with 4 columns

```
 home_id (primary_key)  
 title (varchar)
 price (double)
 location_id (foreign key)
```

And I have another table

`locations` with 3 columns

```
 location_id (primary key)
 location_name (varchar)
 location_state (varchar)
```

I just want to make these two queries

`SELECT * FROM homes_info WHERE title = 'xxxxx' && price = 'xxxx'`

`SELECT * FROM homes_info LEFT JOIN locations on homes_info.location_id = locations.location_id WHERE title = 'xxx' && price = 'xxxxx' && location_name = 'xxxx'`

are the following the best way to use indexes on above tables for optimizing above two queries?

`ALTER TABLE homes_info ADD INDEX(title, price)`

`ALTER TABLE locations ADD INDEX(location_name)`

I know for the first query the composite index `INDEX(title, price)` is better than separate indexes, But what about the second query (where I used `LEFT JOIN`)? would using separate indexes on `title` and `price` columns  be better for the second query

In simple words,
 what would be the best use of indexes on those two tables for optimizing above two queries?

Thanks!

Comment: `ALTER TABLE locations ADD INDEX(location_name)` (I think you mean `locations` table instead of `home_info`)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes, you are right, sry, i am editing it now

Comment: @user9050678, Just FYI, The thumb rule is to create an index on all the columns included in Where clause and in Join condition. Since you have to use 2 different queries so I would suggest that create a composite index on (title, price) and a different index on location_name. Location_id already had an index being the primary key for locations table.

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but there are many SO answers on whether the order of an index matters and how.  Like Ankit said, your index and where/on should have the same fields; this explains a bit more, if you want to know finer differences -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24315519/2430549

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Thanks, I thought the same but the scaisEdge answer says differently, i will do some more research myself, and update that here, Thanks

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for table  location you could use  y .. you could use single composite

```
ALTER TABLE locations ADD locations_info INDEX(location_name , localtion_id)
```

using a composite with localtion_name and location_id) you are sure that all the infor needed  by the where (join ) clause are resolved by the index, avoiding the acces  to the data table for get  .. the location_id

Comment: hi, sorry, there was a mistake in question,  `ALTER TABLE locations ADD INDEX(location_name)` instead of `ALTER TABLE homes_info ADD INDEX(location_name)`

Comment: update  your question  .. so i can answer properly  .. (happen)

Comment: hi, thanks, but I am still confused, why we need to use an index on `location_id`, it is a primary key so already indexed? and what about first table, is using composite index ok on first table's columns ?could you explain little bit more pls

Comment: simple  ..  using composite index  .. both the info  for where are in the same  index  .. so with a single access  you have both the info ..  and query optimizer  can use just one index for a table  in a query  ..  in your case   the query optimizer  use  the index with  primary key  but this index have not the info  for name so this part of info must be retrived  with an acces to the data table  ...  hope is clear

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, so for  this query `SELECT * FROM homes_info LEFT JOIN locations on homes_info.location_id = locations.location_id WHERE title = 'xxx' && price = 'xxxxx' && location_name = 'xxxx'` The best use of indexes would be `ALTER TABLE homes_info ADD INDEX(title, price)` and `ALTER TABLE locations ADD INDEX(location_name, location_id)` so actually we don't need to  worry about the JOIN, we should think how should we use indexes on the two tables for best performance (separately) considering which column from that table we are using in join query

Comment: Oh, but then we should use this index on first table `ALTER TABLE homes_info ADD INDEX(title, price, location_id)`, i am very confused now, could you pls shed some light on this

Comment: i have not (more)  then index (title, price, location_id) .. is unuseful for the first query  and unuseful for the second query  ... you need  INDEX(title, price) for the first query and I NDEX(location_name , localtion_id)  for the second query   .. the second query  using two table  .. use both the index ..