# Does mysql covering index follow leftmost index prefix?

Tags: mysql

AS I know, the multiple-column indexes should follow leftmost prefix principle.

And as the mysql documention: 
The optimizer attempts to use additional key parts to determine the interval as long as the comparison operator is =, <=>, or IS NULL. If the operator is >, <, >=, <=, !=, <>, BETWEEN, or LIKE, the optimizer uses it but considers no more key parts.

But I find the convering index does not  follow leftmost prefix .

for example:

mysql 5.6.16

show create table t_covering_index\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t_covering_index
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_covering_index` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `col3` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `col4` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `col5` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `col6` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `col7` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col8` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col9` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_col7_col9_col8_col6` (`col7`,`col9`,`col8`,`col6`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1024 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

explain select col6 from t_covering_index where col7='10060000041162' and col9>='2019-02-01' and col9< '2019-02-28' and col8=1;
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t_covering_index | range | idx_col7_col9_col8_col6 | idx_col7_col9_col8_col6 | 109     | NULL |    2 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

explain select col6 from t_covering_index where col9>='2019-02-01' and col9< '2019-02-28' and col8=1;
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key                     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t_covering_index | index | NULL          | idx_col7_col9_col8_col6 | 118     | NULL |  371 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

INSERT INTO `t_covering_index` VALUES (91,'30061901301897673663',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000028619',1,'2019-01-30 19:35:05'),(124,'30061902040091016037',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000032601',1,'2019-02-13 14:44:22'),(140,'30061902131071212621',-3000,-3000,0,1,0,'10060000035146',1,'2019-02-13 18:56:21'),(150,'30061902132224866441',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000037174',1,'2019-02-13 23:00:23'),(154,'30061902132225051119',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000037161',1,'2019-02-13 23:03:22'),(174,'30061902132337694942',2000,2000,0,1,0,'10060000037189',1,'2019-02-13 23:47:28'),(175,'30061902132337694942',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000037189',1,'2019-02-13 23:55:15'),(176,'30061902132337694942',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000037189',1,'2019-02-13 23:55:15'),(178,'30061902132249641789',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000037173',1,'2019-02-14 11:28:19'),(179,'30061902132355414357',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000037181',1,'2019-02-14 11:28:23'),(180,'30061902132355414357',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000037181',1,'2019-02-14 11:28:23'),(181,'30061902132355414357',0,0,0,1,0,'10060000037181',1,'2019-02-14 11:28:23'),(186,'30061902141034666728',1000,1000,0,1,0,'10060000037194',1,'2019-02-14 14:21:52'),(187,'30061902141034666728',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000037194',1,'2019-02-14 14:22:49'),(190,'30061902132203340401',4000,4000,0,1,0,'10060000037142',1,'2019-02-14 17:35:54'),(213,'30061902132269345355',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000037141',1,'2019-02-14 17:49:16'),(214,'30061902132269345355',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000037141',1,'2019-02-14 17:49:16'),(278,'30061902132262689372',-2000,-2000,0,0,0,'10060000037140',1,'2019-02-14 18:56:29'),(279,'30061902132262689372',-1600,-1600,0,0,0,'10060000037140',1,'2019-02-14 18:58:54'),(293,'30061902141872019379',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000041162',1,'2019-02-14 19:27:04'),(294,'30061902141872019379',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000041162',1,'2019-02-14 19:27:04'),(295,'30061902141872019379',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000041162',1,'2019-02-14 19:27:04'),(296,'30061902141998854383',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000045604',1,'2019-02-14 19:31:43'),(297,'30061902141998854383',1800,1800,0,0,0,'10060000045604',1,'2019-02-14 19:31:43'),(298,'30061902141998854383',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000045604',1,'2019-02-14 19:31:43'),(299,'30061902141922920059',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045603',1,'2019-02-14 19:32:23'),(300,'30061902141922920059',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045603',1,'2019-02-14 19:32:23'),(301,'30061902141922920059',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045603',1,'2019-02-14 19:32:23'),(302,'30061902141991238963',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045606',1,'2019-02-14 19:37:13'),(303,'30061902141991238963',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045606',1,'2019-02-14 19:37:14'),(304,'30061902141991238963',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045606',1,'2019-02-14 19:37:14'),(305,'30061902141941167013',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045605',1,'2019-02-14 19:38:20'),(306,'30061902141941167013',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045605',1,'2019-02-14 19:38:20'),(307,'30061902141941167013',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045605',1,'2019-02-14 19:38:20'),(308,'30061902141893544998',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000041153',1,'2019-02-14 19:40:33'),(309,'30061902141893544998',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000041153',1,'2019-02-14 19:40:33'),(310,'30061902141893544998',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000041153',1,'2019-02-14 19:40:33'),(311,'30061902141915291201',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045608',1,'2019-02-14 19:41:49'),(312,'30061902141915291201',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045608',1,'2019-02-14 19:41:49'),(313,'30061902141915291201',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045608',1,'2019-02-14 19:41:49'),(314,'30061902141938487224',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045611',1,'2019-02-14 19:52:59'),(315,'30061902141938487224',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045611',1,'2019-02-14 19:52:59'),(316,'30061902141938487224',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045611',1,'2019-02-14 19:52:59'),(317,'30061902141941360260',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000045615',1,'2019-02-14 19:57:36'),(318,'30061902141941360260',1800,1800,0,0,0,'10060000045615',1,'2019-02-14 19:57:36'),(319,'30061902141941360260',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000045615',1,'2019-02-14 19:57:36'),(320,'30061902142052667979',4000,4000,0,0,0,'10060000045617',1,'2019-02-14 20:03:31'),(321,'30061902142052667979',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000045617',1,'2019-02-14 20:03:31'),(322,'30061902142099544525',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045630',1,'2019-02-14 20:23:15'),(323,'30061902142099544525',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045630',1,'2019-02-14 20:23:15'),(324,'30061902142099544525',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045630',1,'2019-02-14 20:23:15'),(325,'30061902142017309601',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045633',1,'2019-02-14 20:26:34'),(326,'30061902142017309601',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045633',1,'2019-02-14 20:26:34'),(327,'30061902142017309601',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045633',1,'2019-02-14 20:26:35'),(328,'30061902142031355235',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045634',1,'2019-02-14 20:38:21'),(329,'30061902142031355235',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045634',1,'2019-02-14 20:38:21'),(330,'30061902142031355235',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045634',1,'2019-02-14 20:38:21'),(331,'30061902142099838393',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045635',1,'2019-02-14 20:39:27'),(332,'30061902142099838393',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045635',1,'2019-02-14 20:39:27'),(333,'30061902142099838393',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045635',1,'2019-02-14 20:39:27'),(334,'30061902142074083703',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000045648',1,'2019-02-14 20:57:38'),(335,'30061902142074083703',1800,1800,0,0,0,'10060000045648',1,'2019-02-14 20:57:37'),(336,'30061902142074083703',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000045648',1,'2019-02-14 20:57:37'),(337,'30061902142074083703',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000045648',1,'2019-02-14 20:57:37'),(338,'30061902142020987456',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045636',1,'2019-02-14 21:03:36'),(339,'30061902142020987456',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045636',1,'2019-02-14 21:03:36'),(340,'30061902142020987456',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045636',1,'2019-02-14 21:03:36'),(341,'30061902142184139980',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045649',1,'2019-02-14 21:04:23'),(342,'30061902142184139980',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045649',1,'2019-02-14 21:04:23'),(343,'30061902142184139980',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045649',1,'2019-02-14 21:04:23'),(344,'30061902142146588050',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045656',1,'2019-02-14 21:06:27'),(345,'30061902142146588050',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045656',1,'2019-02-14 21:06:27'),(346,'30061902142146588050',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045656',1,'2019-02-14 21:06:27'),(347,'30061902142134909099',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000045686',1,'2019-02-14 21:13:45'),(348,'30061902142134909099',1800,1800,0,0,0,'10060000045686',1,'2019-02-14 21:13:44'),(349,'30061902142134909099',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000045686',1,'2019-02-14 21:13:44'),(350,'30061902150957771656',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045709',1,'2019-02-15 09:45:01'),(351,'30061902150957771656',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045709',1,'2019-02-15 09:45:01'),(352,'30061902150957771656',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045709',1,'2019-02-15 09:45:01'),(353,'30061902150957771656',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000045709',1,'2019-02-15 09:45:01'),(356,'30061902151129010655',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000047622',1,'2019-02-15 11:36:32'),(357,'30061902151129010655',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000047622',1,'2019-02-15 11:36:32'),(358,'30061902151288725840',4000,4000,0,0,0,'10060000047630',1,'2019-02-15 12:52:30'),(359,'30061902151288725840',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000047630',1,'2019-02-15 12:52:30'),(360,'30061902151479911712',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000049104',1,'2019-02-15 14:13:26'),(361,'30061902151479911712',1800,1800,0,0,0,'10060000049104',1,'2019-02-15 14:13:28'),(362,'30061902151479911712',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000049104',1,'2019-02-15 14:13:28'),(363,'30061902151493895630',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000049117',1,'2019-02-15 14:44:15'),(364,'30061902151493895630',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000049117',1,'2019-02-15 14:44:16'),(365,'30061902151493895630',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000049117',1,'2019-02-15 14:44:16'),(366,'30061902151496406116',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000049116',1,'2019-02-15 14:45:43'),(367,'30061902151496406116',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000049116',1,'2019-02-15 14:45:44'),(368,'30061902151496406116',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000049116',1,'2019-02-15 14:45:45'),(369,'30061902151506893144',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000049130',1,'2019-02-15 15:28:26'),(370,'30061902151506893144',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000049130',1,'2019-02-15 15:28:27'),(371,'30061902151506893144',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000049130',1,'2019-02-15 15:28:27'),(375,'30061902151533201967',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000049128',1,'2019-02-15 16:01:51'),(376,'30061902151533201967',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000049128',1,'2019-02-15 16:01:51'),(377,'30061902151533201967',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000049128',1,'2019-02-15 16:01:51'),(378,'30061902151604071505',4000,4000,0,0,0,'10060000050107',1,'2019-02-15 16:08:01'),(384,'30061902151664059033',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000050108',1,'2019-02-15 16:18:54'),(385,'30061902151664059033',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000050108',1,'2019-02-15 16:18:54'),(386,'30061902151664059033',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000050108',1,'2019-02-15 16:18:54'),(387,'30061902151676118374',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050111',1,'2019-02-15 16:35:21'),(388,'30061902151676118374',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050111',1,'2019-02-15 16:35:21'),(389,'30061902151650026897',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000050114',1,'2019-02-15 16:55:26'),(390,'30061902151650026897',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000050114',1,'2019-02-15 16:55:26'),(391,'30061902151650026897',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000050114',1,'2019-02-15 16:55:26'),(392,'30061902151727190495',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050116',1,'2019-02-15 17:01:16'),(393,'30061902151727190495',900,900,0,0,0,'10060000050116',1,'2019-02-15 17:01:16'),(394,'30061902151727190495',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000050116',1,'2019-02-15 17:01:16'),(396,'30061902151916911111',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050134',1,'2019-02-15 19:07:43'),(397,'30061902151916911111',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050134',1,'2019-02-15 19:07:43'),(398,'30061902151705126512',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050124',1,'2019-02-15 19:40:22'),(399,'30061902151991937673',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050155',1,'2019-02-15 19:47:15'),(400,'30061902142059695446',500,500,0,0,0,'10060000045627',1,'2019-02-15 19:50:08'),(401,'30061902142059695446',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000045627',1,'2019-02-15 19:50:08'),(402,'30061902151943316958',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050159',1,'2019-02-15 20:07:33'),(403,'30061902151943316958',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000050159',1,'2019-02-15 20:07:34'),(404,'30061902152085633314',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050161',1,'2019-02-15 20:09:18'),(405,'30061902152070826142',1500,1500,0,0,0,'10060000050163',1,'2019-02-15 20:16:06'),(406,'30061902152070826142',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050163',1,'2019-02-15 20:16:07'),(407,'30061902152039515145',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050164',1,'2019-02-15 20:16:53'),(408,'30061902152010753666',1500,1500,0,0,0,'10060000050166',1,'2019-02-15 20:40:39'),(409,'30061902152010753666',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050166',1,'2019-02-15 20:40:39'),(410,'30061902152120436990',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050170',1,'2019-02-15 21:04:01'),(411,'30061902152120436990',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000050170',1,'2019-02-15 21:04:02'),(412,'30061902160925301198',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050174',1,'2019-02-16 09:47:43'),(413,'30061902160925301198',1350,1350,0,0,0,'10060000050174',1,'2019-02-16 09:47:43'),(414,'30061902160925301198',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050174',1,'2019-02-16 09:47:43'),(424,'30061902161035073621',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000050198',1,'2019-02-16 10:42:52'),(425,'30061902161035073621',1800,1800,0,0,0,'10060000050198',1,'2019-02-16 10:42:51'),(426,'30061902161035073621',810,810,0,0,0,'10060000050198',1,'2019-02-16 10:42:51'),(427,'30061902161035073621',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000050198',1,'2019-02-16 10:42:51'),(428,'30061902161026699563',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050175',1,'2019-02-16 10:57:26'),(430,'30061902161026699563',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050175',1,'2019-02-16 10:57:49'),(431,'30061902161026699563',960,960,0,0,0,'10060000050175',1,'2019-02-16 10:57:49'),(432,'30061902151340895478',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000049101',1,'2019-02-16 11:16:36'),(433,'30061902151340895478',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000049101',1,'2019-02-16 11:16:37'),(434,'30061902141131554852',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000037199',1,'2019-02-16 11:18:02'),(435,'30061902141131554852',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000037199',1,'2019-02-16 11:18:04'),(436,'30061902141436147552',4000,4000,0,0,0,'10060000039103',1,'2019-02-16 11:18:09'),(437,'30061902141436147552',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000039103',1,'2019-02-16 11:18:10'),(438,'30061902141274250095',4000,4000,0,0,0,'10060000037200',1,'2019-02-16 11:18:15'),(439,'30061902141274250095',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000037200',1,'2019-02-16 11:18:16'),(440,'30061902141452849929',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000039104',1,'2019-02-16 11:18:21'),(441,'30061902141452849929',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000039104',1,'2019-02-16 11:18:23'),(442,'30061902141452849929',0,0,0,0,0,'10060000039104',1,'2019-02-16 11:18:23'),(443,'30061902151348696267',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000049103',1,'2019-02-16 11:19:16'),(444,'30061902151348696267',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000049103',1,'2019-02-16 11:19:17'),(798,'30061902161424793044',4000,4000,0,0,0,'10060000050220',1,'2019-02-16 14:17:09'),(799,'30061902161424793044',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000050220',1,'2019-02-16 14:17:09'),(800,'30061902161481482681',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050221',1,'2019-02-16 14:17:49'),(801,'30061902161481482681',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050221',1,'2019-02-16 14:17:50'),(802,'30061902161181109462',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050208',1,'2019-02-16 14:17:54'),(803,'30061902161181109462',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050208',1,'2019-02-16 14:17:54'),(804,'30061902161181109462',960,960,0,0,0,'10060000050208',1,'2019-02-16 14:17:54'),(805,'30061902161197506069',200000,200000,0,0,0,'10060000050202',1,'2019-02-16 14:18:45'),(806,'30061902161197506069',180000,180000,0,0,0,'10060000050202',1,'2019-02-16 14:18:45'),(807,'30061902161197506069',81000,81000,0,0,0,'10060000050202',1,'2019-02-16 14:18:45'),(808,'30061902161197506069',160000,160000,0,0,0,'10060000050202',1,'2019-02-16 14:18:45'),(809,'30061902161410169351',4000,4000,0,0,0,'10060000050222',1,'2019-02-16 14:21:04'),(810,'30061902161410169351',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000050222',1,'2019-02-16 14:21:05'),(811,'30061902161160762886',4000,4000,0,0,0,'10060000050209',1,'2019-02-16 14:23:18'),(812,'30061902161160762886',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000050209',1,'2019-02-16 14:23:18'),(813,'30061902161114183570',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050210',1,'2019-02-16 14:24:47'),(814,'30061902161114183570',900,900,0,0,0,'10060000050210',1,'2019-02-16 14:24:47'),(815,'30061902161114183570',405,405,0,0,0,'10060000050210',1,'2019-02-16 14:24:47'),(816,'30061902161114183570',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000050210',1,'2019-02-16 14:24:47'),(817,'30061902161164420607',200000,200000,0,0,0,'10060000050212',1,'2019-02-16 14:38:24'),(818,'30061902161164420607',180000,180000,0,0,0,'10060000050212',1,'2019-02-16 14:38:24'),(819,'30061902161164420607',81000,81000,0,0,0,'10060000050212',1,'2019-02-16 14:38:24'),(820,'30061902161164420607',160000,160000,0,0,0,'10060000050212',1,'2019-02-16 14:38:24'),(821,'30061902161195522087',4000,4000,0,0,0,'10060000050213',1,'2019-02-16 14:42:11'),(822,'30061902161195522087',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000050213',1,'2019-02-16 14:42:12'),(823,'30061902161590920474',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050230',1,'2019-02-16 15:06:30'),(824,'30061902161590920474',1350,1350,0,0,0,'10060000050230',1,'2019-02-16 15:06:30'),(825,'30061902161590920474',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050230',1,'2019-02-16 15:06:30'),(826,'30061902161581563513',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050232',1,'2019-02-16 15:29:46'),(827,'30061902161581563513',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050232',1,'2019-02-16 15:29:46'),(828,'30061902161581563513',960,960,0,0,0,'10060000050232',1,'2019-02-16 15:29:46'),(829,'30061902161573331145',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050239',1,'2019-02-16 15:53:26'),(830,'30061902161573331145',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050239',1,'2019-02-16 15:53:26'),(831,'30061902161573331145',960,960,0,0,0,'10060000050239',1,'2019-02-16 15:53:26'),(832,'30061902161663730544',200000,200000,0,0,0,'10060000050240',1,'2019-02-16 16:04:35'),(833,'30061902161663730544',180000,180000,0,0,0,'10060000050240',1,'2019-02-16 16:04:35'),(834,'30061902161663730544',80000,80000,0,0,0,'10060000050240',1,'2019-02-16 16:04:35'),(835,'30061902161663730544',32000,32000,0,0,0,'10060000050240',1,'2019-02-16 16:04:35'),(836,'30061902161605863154',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050248',1,'2019-02-16 16:08:42'),(837,'30061902161605863154',1350,1350,0,0,0,'10060000050248',1,'2019-02-16 16:08:42'),(838,'30061902161605863154',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050248',1,'2019-02-16 16:08:42'),(839,'30061902161605863154',960,960,0,0,0,'10060000050248',1,'2019-02-16 16:08:42'),(840,'30061902161670834864',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050250',1,'2019-02-16 16:11:28'),(841,'30061902161670834864',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050250',1,'2019-02-16 16:11:28'),(842,'30061902161670834864',960,960,0,0,0,'10060000050250',1,'2019-02-16 16:11:28'),(843,'30061902161150548403',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050207',1,'2019-02-16 16:13:35'),(844,'30061902161150548403',900,900,0,0,0,'10060000050207',1,'2019-02-16 16:13:35'),(845,'30061902161150548403',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000050207',1,'2019-02-16 16:13:35'),(846,'30061902161602298589',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050269',1,'2019-02-16 16:54:38'),(847,'30061902161705902166',6000,6000,0,0,0,'10060000050273',1,'2019-02-16 17:09:14'),(848,'30061902161788000550',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000050274',1,'2019-02-16 17:12:53'),(849,'30061902161785643267',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000050275',1,'2019-02-16 17:12:55'),(850,'30061902161792735265',15000,15000,0,0,0,'10060000050276',1,'2019-02-16 17:14:47'),(851,'30061902161762296558',6000,6000,0,0,0,'10060000050277',1,'2019-02-16 17:21:32'),(852,'30061902161701603136',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050280',1,'2019-02-16 17:25:26'),(853,'30061902161716659451',-2000,-2000,0,0,0,'10060000050283',1,'2019-02-16 17:38:55'),(854,'30061902161716659451',-1600,-1600,0,0,0,'10060000050283',1,'2019-02-16 17:38:55'),(855,'30061902161716659451',-640,-640,0,0,0,'10060000050283',1,'2019-02-16 17:38:55'),(856,'30061902161725902328',5000,5000,0,0,0,'10060000050287',1,'2019-02-16 17:54:37'),(857,'30061902161843177364',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050289',1,'2019-02-16 18:02:51'),(858,'30061902161843177364',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050289',1,'2019-02-16 18:02:51'),(859,'30061902161843177364',960,960,0,0,0,'10060000050289',1,'2019-02-16 18:02:51'),(860,'30061902161814686870',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050290',1,'2019-02-16 18:03:47'),(861,'30061902161814686870',1350,1350,0,0,0,'10060000050290',1,'2019-02-16 18:03:47'),(862,'30061902161814686870',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050290',1,'2019-02-16 18:03:47'),(863,'30061902161814040230',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050291',1,'2019-02-16 18:09:11'),(864,'30061902161814040230',900,900,0,0,0,'10060000050291',1,'2019-02-16 18:09:11'),(865,'30061902161814040230',405,405,0,0,0,'10060000050291',1,'2019-02-16 18:09:11'),(866,'30061902161814040230',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000050291',1,'2019-02-16 18:09:11'),(867,'30061902161878032147',5000,5000,0,0,0,'10060000050295',1,'2019-02-16 18:14:37'),(868,'30061902161878986165',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050300',1,'2019-02-16 18:17:29'),(869,'30061902161882524001',-2000,-2000,0,0,0,'10060000050301',1,'2019-02-16 18:20:11'),(871,'30061902161828922133',-2000,-2000,0,0,0,'10060000050302',1,'2019-02-16 18:20:42'),(873,'30061902161834459551',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050304',1,'2019-02-16 18:25:41'),(874,'30061902161803924562',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050309',1,'2019-02-16 18:40:43'),(875,'30061902161803924562',1350,1350,0,0,0,'10060000050309',1,'2019-02-16 18:40:43'),(876,'30061902161803924562',2400,2400,0,0,0,'10060000050309',1,'2019-02-16 18:40:43'),(877,'30061902161803924562',960,960,0,0,0,'10060000050309',1,'2019-02-16 18:40:43'),(878,'30061902161868132800',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000050311',1,'2019-02-16 18:43:38'),(879,'30061902161868132800',1800,1800,0,0,0,'10060000050311',1,'2019-02-16 18:43:38'),(880,'30061902161868132800',810,810,0,0,0,'10060000050311',1,'2019-02-16 18:43:38'),(881,'30061902161868132800',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000050311',1,'2019-02-16 18:43:38'),(882,'30061902161868132800',640,640,0,0,0,'10060000050311',1,'2019-02-16 18:43:38'),(883,'30061902161811738683',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000050313',1,'2019-02-16 18:55:29'),(884,'30061902161972545967',-2000,-2000,0,0,0,'10060000050316',1,'2019-02-16 19:01:17'),(885,'30061902161991079235',6000,6000,0,0,0,'10060000050321',1,'2019-02-16 19:28:19'),(886,'30061902161942730597',6000,6000,0,0,0,'10060000050322',1,'2019-02-16 19:29:25'),(887,'30061902161978527679',6000,6000,0,0,0,'10060000050323',1,'2019-02-16 19:29:44'),(888,'30061902161952036050',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050325',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:38'),(889,'30061902161952036050',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000050325',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:38'),(890,'30061902161952036050',900,900,0,0,0,'10060000050325',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:38'),(891,'30061902161952036050',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000050325',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:38'),(892,'30061902161952036050',320,320,0,0,0,'10060000050325',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:38'),(893,'30061902161901117419',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000050326',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:54'),(894,'30061902161901117419',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000050326',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:54'),(895,'30061902161901117419',900,900,0,0,0,'10060000050326',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:54'),(896,'30061902161901117419',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000050326',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:54'),(897,'30061902161901117419',320,320,0,0,0,'10060000050326',1,'2019-02-16 19:30:54'),(898,'30061902171875618507',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000051604',1,'2019-02-17 18:06:01'),(899,'30061902171875618507',1800,1800,0,0,0,'10060000051604',1,'2019-02-17 18:06:01'),(900,'30061902171875618507',810,810,0,0,0,'10060000051604',1,'2019-02-17 18:06:01'),(901,'30061902171875618507',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000051604',1,'2019-02-17 18:06:01'),(902,'30061902171875618507',640,640,0,0,0,'10060000051604',1,'2019-02-17 18:06:01'),(903,'30061902181075319728',-1000,-1000,0,0,0,'10060000051606',1,'2019-02-18 10:04:36'),(904,'30061902181075319728',-400,-400,0,0,0,'10060000051606',1,'2019-02-18 10:04:36'),(905,'30061902181017721693',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000051644',1,'2019-02-18 10:47:26'),(906,'30061902181017721693',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000051644',1,'2019-02-18 10:47:27'),(907,'30061902181017721693',640,640,0,0,0,'10060000051644',1,'2019-02-18 10:47:27'),(908,'30061902181117363245',2000,2000,0,0,0,'10060000051650',1,'2019-02-18 11:23:25'),(909,'30061902181117363245',1600,1600,0,0,0,'10060000051650',1,'2019-02-18 11:23:25'),(910,'30061902181117363245',640,640,0,0,0,'10060000051650',1,'2019-02-18 11:23:25'),(911,'30061902181173388014',3000,3000,0,0,0,'10060000051655',1,'2019-02-18 11:45:07'),(912,'30061902181307845357',5000,5000,0,0,0,'10060000051659',1,'2019-02-18 13:52:04'),(913,'30061902181407840471',5000,5000,0,0,0,'10060000051665',1,'2019-02-18 14:11:48'),(914,'30061902181446050443',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000051664',1,'2019-02-18 14:20:03'),(915,'30061902181446050443',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000051664',1,'2019-02-18 14:20:16'),(916,'30061902181446050443',320,320,0,0,0,'10060000051664',1,'2019-02-18 14:20:17'),(917,'30061902181460371290',1000,1000,0,0,0,'10060000053605',1,'2019-02-18 14:25:42'),(918,'30061902181460371290',800,800,0,0,0,'10060000053605',1,'2019-02-18 14:25:42'),(919,'30061902181460371290',320,320,0,0,0,'10060000053605',1,'2019-02-18 14:25:42'),(920,'30061902181471894041',5000,5000,0,0,0,'10060000053606',1,'2019-02-18 14:31:36'),(924,'30061902181449364547',5000,5000,0,0,0,'10060000053616',1,'2019-02-18 14:55:17'),(925,'30061902181576624754',10000,10000,0,0,0,'10060000053619',1,'2019-02-18 15:11:22'),(926,'30061902181528837411',-4000,-4000,0,0,0,'10060000053623',1,'2019-02-18 15:39:32'),(927,'30061902181528837411',-3600,-3600,0,0,0,'10060000053623',1,'2019-02-18 15:39:32'),(928,'30061902181528837411',-3200,-3200,0,0,0,'10060000053623',1,'2019-02-18 15:39:32'),(929,'30061902181582730067',-2000,-2000,0,0,0,'10060000053625',1,'2019-02-18 15:41:13'),(930,'30061902181511306989',-4000,-4000,0,0,0,'10060000053626',1,'2019-02-18 15:41:36'),(931,'30061902181511306989',-3600,-3600,0,0,0,'10060000053626',1,'2019-02-18 15:41:36'),(932,'30061902181511306989',-3200,-3200,0,0,0,'10060000053626',1,'2019-02-18 15:41:36'),(933,'30061902181539240482',-4000,-4000,0,0,0,'10060000053627',1,'2019-02-18 15:42:18');

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the styling of your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code on how to post code blocks.

Comment: What is the actual question you have? You haven't asked anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Order of Fields of Multi-Column Index in MySQL Matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315151/does-order-of-fields-of-multi-column-index-in-mysql-matter)