# SQL Indexing not improving speed

Tags: sql, database, indexing

Given an SQL database with index for `(startpage, endpage)`, with a relation `Articles(*ID*, title, startpage, endpage)`, why isn't a query

```
SELECT title 
FROM Articles 
WHERE endpage = 100;
```

sped up by the previous index?

Apologies for this peculiar question as it came from a practice paper without explanation.

Comment: you need to either create separate index `(endpage, title)` or at least swap `(endpage, startpage)` in existing one

Comment: Could you please specify RDBMS you use. One explanation can be that table Articles is very small and engine does not need to use index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the index shown does not help that query: because `endpage` is not the leftmost column of the index.

See my answer to [Does Order of Fields of Multi-Column Index in MySQL Matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315151/does-order-of-fields-of-multi-column-index-in-mysql-matter/24315527#24315527) for more explanation (that question is about MySQL, but the answer should apply to any implementation of B-tree indexes).

Comment: Thank you for that excellent explanation. If I could ask an extension of this question, for an index (a,b), would a query asking (WHERE a=1 AND b=2) be different from (WHERE b=2 AND a=1)? It seems that the 2nd query would be longer unless sql processes AND queries differently

Comment: Some dbms's have skip-scan. I.e. can take advantage of the index even for its second column.

Comment: @jarlh, Thanks, that's a good point, the OP did not specify which product they use.

Comment: @vernal123, It depends on the implementation, but in products I've used, the order of `AND` terms wouldn't matter in the example you show, because the optimizer knows that `AND` expressions are commutative. Use EXPLAIN to test the optimizer plan on your database.

Comment: Apologies! Because this question came from a practice paper, there was no DBMS specified. In our labs we have been using mysql however

Comment: @jarlh, MySQL 8.0.13 is the first version that supports skip-scan, but I think a search would be optimized much better if the column(s) to be searched were the leftmost columns of the index.

Comment: @BillKarwin, absolutely. Skip-scan is just the second choice.