# Should I begin a MySQL index with unique or non-unique field?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

The problem I have is the following:

- I have a table that contains about 100000000 rows
- it has 22 fields - some numeric, some text
- it has a primary key `id` (auto-incremented integer)
- it has a field `another_id` of type `bigint`, and a unique key on it
- it has a field called `state` that can take only 4 integer values (0 to 3)
- I need that the queries of the following form are executed as fast as possible:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE another_id IN ( <about 100 values> ) 
AND state = ...
```

for different values of `state`.

How should the index look like? I was thinking about two options:

- `KEY another_id:state (another_id, state)`
- `KEY state:another_id (state, another_id)`

Is there any difference in performance between those two variants? Is there anything else to consider?

Edit: engine is InnoDB

Comment: If a column can only take 4 values, it's not going to be a very good discriminant (its cardinality is not very high). OTOH, a unique column is very discriminating. So you should put the unique index first in the composite index.

Answer (score 1):

For the query you show, you should create the index with `state`, `another_id` in that order.

Define the index with any columns referenced in *equality* conditions first, after them add one column referenced in a *range* condition or ORDER BY or GROUP BY.

You may also like my answer to [Does Order of Fields of Multi-Column Index in MySQL Matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315151/does-order-of-fields-of-multi-column-index-in-mysql-matter/24315527#24315527) or my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: About "column referenced in a range condition":

In my question, there is an "IN" condition (a value from a given set), not a range condition - would it influence your answer?

Comment: I count any expression other than `=` or `IS NULL` as a range condition. They all follow the principle I described above, whether they are `IN()`, `BETWEEN`, `>`, `<`, `!=`, or even `IS NOT NULL`. If the condition can match multiple values, i.e. it's not an equality condition, therefore it's in the broad category of range conditions.

Comment: So far, there were two responses to my question, and they contradict each other :)

Comment: @barmar says the order should be "another_id, state" because the IDs (which are unique) are more discriminating than the states; 

Bill Karwin (this answer) says the order should be "state, another_id" because the condition on another_id is not an equality but can match multiple values.

I agree that both points might be valid - is there any way to decide which of those considerations outweigh the other? As the additional context - the DB engine is InnoDB, so I believe HASH/BTREE choice is done for me by the DB.

Comment: Yes, you can determine by testing both suggestions. Use EXPLAIN to see how they are using the columns of the index. Using performance profiling to see how many rows they have to read, and ultimately how fast they are. See my presentation [SQL query patterns, optimized](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-query-patterns-optimized) for techniques of measuring.

Comment: @AndreySh - Cardinality does _not_ factor into this or similar index questions.  Bill's answer is correct.  Think of it from the metric of how many 'rows' in the index need to be looked at.  If necessary, then look at how spread out those rows are, especially in light of the blocking in InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above. One clarification though is that you want to have ita hash index not btree index. It should work faster. The hash index wouldn't work well with any queries that involve inequality such as <=

Comment: The answers are sorted by votes, so "above answer" means nothing.  Also, this should have been a comment on that answer.  You may not be able to leave a comment yet, you just have to be patient.

Comment: MySQL's default storage engine, InnoDB, does not support hash indexes.

Comment: A hash index [though not available] would fail poorly if it had a lot of collisions.