# MySQL - Best methods to provide fast Dynamic filter support for large-scale database record lists?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, prepared-statement, common-table-expression

I am curious what techniques Database Developers and Architects use to create dynamic filter data response Stored Procedures (or Functions) for large-scale databases.

For example, let's take a database with millions of people in it, and we want to provide a stored procedure "get-person-list" which takes a JSON parameter. Within this JSON parameter, we can define filters such as $.filter.name.first, $.filter.name.last, $.filter.phone.number, $.filter.address.city, etc.

The frontend (web solution) allows the user to define one or more filters, so the front-end can say "Show me everyone with a First name of Ted and last name of Smith in San Diego."

The payload would look like this:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "name": {
            "last": "smith",
            "first": "ted"
        },
        "address": {
            "city": "san diego"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what would the best technique be to write a single stored procedure capable of handling numerous (dozens or more) filter settings (dynamically) and returning the proper result set all with the best optimization/speed?

Is it possible to do this with CTE, or are prepared statements based on IF/THEN logic (building out the SQL to be executed based on filter value) the best/only real method?

How do big companies with huge databases and thousands of users write their calls to return complex dynamic lists of data as quickly as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything Bill wrote is true, and good advice.

I'll take it a little further. You're proposing building a search layer into your system, which is fine.

You're proposing an interface in which you pass a JSON object to code inside the DBMS.**That's not fine.**  That code will either have a bunch of canned queries handling the various search scenarios, or will have a mess of string-handling code that reads JSON, puts together appropriate queries, then uses [MySQL's PREPARE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html) to run them.  From my experience that is, with respect, *a really bad idea*.

Here's why:

1. The stored-procedure language has very weak string-handling support compared to host languages. No sprintf. No arrays of strings. No join or implode operators. Clunky regex, and not always present on every server. You're going to need string handling to build search queries.
2. Stored procedures are trickier to debug, test, deploy, and maintain than ordinary application code. That work requires special skills and special access.
3. You will need to maintain this code, especially if your system proves successful. You'll add requirements that will require expanding your search capabilities.
4. It's impossible (seriously, impossible) to know what your actual application usage patterns will be at scale. You surely will, as a consequence of growth, find usage patterns that surprise you. My point is that you can't design and build a search system and then forget about it. It will evolve along with your app.
5. To keep up with evolving usage patterns, you'll need to refactor some queries and add some indexes. *You will be under pressure when you do that work:* People will be complaining about performance. See points 1 and 2 above.
6. MySQL / MariaDB's stored procedures aren't compiled with an optimizing compiler, unlike Oracle and SQL Server's. So there's no compelling performance win.

So don't use a stored procedure for this. Please. Ask me how I know this sometime.

If you need a search module with a JSON interface, implement it in your favorite language (php, C#, nodejs, java, whatever). It will be easier to debug, test, deploy, and maintain.

Comment: I believe this is overall the best answer; however our system is specifically designed to prohibit our Javascript developers from directly accessing our database; they must pass through our Proxy layer, which was the best decision we ever made - our data integrity is rock solid. So I agree native code outside of the DB would have been optimal but logistically, the database handles all requests. As such, I believe prepared statements are the best route to handle the dynamic nature, but your points are correct. Honestly MySQL is lightning fast so far with prepared statements. It's just tedious.

Answer (score 2):

To write a query that searches a variety of columns, you would have to write dynamic SQL. That is, write code to parse your JSON payload for the filter keys and values, and format SQL expressions in a string that is part of a dynamic SQL statement. Then prepare and execute that string.

In general, you can't "optimize for everything." Trying to optimize when you don't know in advance which queries your users will submit is a nigh-impossible task. There's no perfect solution.

The most common method of optimizing search is to create indexes. But you need to know the types of search in advance to create indexes. You need to know which columns will be included, and which types of search operations will be used, because [the column order in an index affects optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315151/does-order-of-fields-of-multi-column-index-in-mysql-matter/24315527#24315527).

For N columns, there are N-factorial permutations of columns, but clearly this is impractical because MySQL only allows 64 indexes per table. You simply can't create all the indexes needed to optimize every possible query your users attempt.

The alternative is to optimize queries partially, by indexing a few combinations of columns, and hope that these help the users' most common queries. Use application logs to determine what the most common queries are.

There are other types of indexes. You could use fulltext indexing, either the implementation built in to MySQL, or else supplement your MySQL database with ElasticSearch or similar technology. These provide a different type of index that effectively indexes everything with one index, so you can search based on multiple columns.

There's no single product that is "best." Which fulltext indexing technology meets your needs requires you to evaluate different products. This is some of the unglamorous work of software development — testing, benchmarking, and matching product features to your application requirements. There are few types of work that I enjoy less. It's a toss-up between this and resolving git merge conflicts.

It's also more work to manage copies of data in multiple datastores, making sure data changes in your SQL database are also copied into the fulltext search index. This involves techniques like ETL (extract, transform, load) and CDC (change data capture).

But you asked how big companies with huge databases do this, and this is how.

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

I to that "all the time".  The web page has a `<form>`.  When submitted, I look for fields of that form that were filled in, then build

```
WHERE this = "..."
  AND that = "..."
```

into the suitable `SELECT` statement.

Note:  I leave out any fields that were not specified in the form; I make sure to escape the strings.

I'm walking through `$_GET[]` instead of `JSON`, so it is quite easy.

**INDEXing**

If you have columns for each possible fields, then it is a matter of providing indexes *only for the most likely columns to search on*.  (There are practical and even hard-coded limits on Indexes.)

If you have stored the attributes in EAV table structure, you have my condolences.  Search the `[entitity-attribute-value]` tag for many other poor soles who wandered into that swamp.

If you store the attributes in JSON, well that is likely to be an order of magnitude worse than EAV.

If you throw all the information in a `FULLTEXT` columns and use `MATCH`, then you can get enough speed for "millions" or rows.  But it comes with various caveats (word length, stoplist, endings, surprise matches, etc).

If you would like to discuss further, then scale back your expectations and make a list of likely search keys.  We can then discuss what technique might be best.