# How to merge several hundred similar mysql tables into a single one without affecting the performance?

Tags: mysql

I have to optimise an existing database serving several hundred objects. Every object periodically inserts data, usually every few seconds, into its own table. All tables have the same columns, datatypes and are not indexed. The tables only differ by content. Each table has a timestamp column

```
select timestamp from object1 limit 3;
+---------------------+
| timestamp           |
+---------------------+
| 2004-01-01 00:00:55 |
| 2004-01-01 00:01:03 |
| 2004-01-01 00:01:05 |
+---------------------+
```

Usually the queries on each individual table are executed over a period of time like this:

```
select timestamp from object1 where timestamp > "2004-01-01 00:00:55" and timestamp < "2004-01-01 00:02:00";
+---------------------+
| timestamp           |
+---------------------+
| 2004-01-01 00:01:03 |
| 2004-01-01 00:01:05 |
| 2004-01-01 00:01:14 |
+---------------------+
```

I want to merge all these tables into a single one and keeping performance. The new common table will have one more column - `objectId`, so that I know what row from which object comes. Also its size is estimated to be about 1 billion records.

The queries that is supposed get executed on that common table are similar to
`select timestamp from objects where timestamp > "2004-01-01 00:00:55" and timestamp < "2004-01-01 00:02:00" and objectid = 12;`

Therefore, I plan to set the engine of that table to InnoDB and index it like so

```
alter table objects engine = InnoDB;
create index index_timestamp_objectid on objects (timestamp, objectid) using BTREE;
```

Bear in mind that this table need to be updated by several thousand records each minute.
I'm particularly worried about the insert queries performance, because they are going to be more often. I'm still not sure if all objects will write in a single `insert` bulk query periodically or every object has to execute its own `insert`.

Question 1. Is that approach good for my needs and what else can be done?
Question 2. What MySql server configuration or Linux host machine configurations can be applied in addition?

Comment: “I want to merge all these tables into a single one and keeping performance”: you won’t. Off topic.

Comment: Index needs to be the other way; in multi column indexes, the column you want a range of comes last.  Otherwise it has to read through index records for all objectids in the timerange

Comment: @user207421 yes, they can.

Comment: @0xC0DEGURU  If the objectid is only the source row number, what value is that to your customer?  It seems to me you also need to know the table_name of the source data.  Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @ysth No he can’t. He is using a wider index with more entries in it. It must be slower.

Comment: Kind of the whole point of indexes is having time proportional to the number of rows of interest, not the total number of rows.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I am reading between the lines a bit, but the OP said "every object ... inserts data ... into its own table." That sounds to me like there's a 1-to-1 relationship between objects and tables, so it should be clear how to add an objectid attribute to the big merged table.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck there is another table in which a row is associated to each objectId. But there isn't any foreign-private relation established between the tables, so I skipped that detail, because it's seems to me irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the query you show, create this index instead:

```
create index obj_objectid_timestamp on objects (objectid, timestamp);
```

(you can name the index whatever you want, this is just an example.)

The order of columns makes a difference. See my answer to [Does Order of Fields of Multi-Column Index in MySQL Matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315151/does-order-of-fields-of-multi-column-index-in-mysql-matter/24315527#24315527) for more explanation.

Briefly: the first column(s) in the index should be those that are used in *equality* conditions, like `objectid = 12`. After such columns, then you can have **one** column that is used in an inequality or range condition. In your case this is `timestamp`.

There is no need to specify `USING BTREE` for an InnoDB table, because it doesn't support hash indexes. I mean, you could specify `USING HASH` but it would ignore that and make a BTREE index anyway.

As for performance of inserts, the performance will generally be proportional to the number of index writes (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html). I hope you had at least one index on `timestamp` on the original tables already, so making a different index on the new table shouldn't result in significantly worse performance with respect to index writes.

You described a rate in the thousands per minute. MySQL (assuming InnoDB) can handle at least an order of magnitude greater rate of inserts. I recall a server at my last job, things got woolly at about 5,000 inserts *per second*.

---

Regarding the comment above denying that your performance will be the same with one table versus many tables. Of course there will be a measurable difference, as there would be with any change. But it may still be within your application's tolerance. This depends on many factors, including your server hardware, the rate of inserts, the level of concurrency, and your specific performance requirements. You won't know until you test it.

Comment: Even better is to have `PRIMARY KEY(objectID, timestamp)`.  If that pair is not guaranteed to be unique, add a third column ``id` and `INDEX(id)`.

Comment: @RickJames Unlikely that pair can be a primary key, because it would block a given objectid from inserting more than one row per second. Also we don't know the table structure, it might already have an auto-inc `id`.

Comment: If you have a thousand objectIDs, there would be a thousand "hot spots" that are well-cached in the buffer_pool.

Comment: Thank you! Once I check your proposals I will let you know how they work!

Comment: Thank you @Bill Karwin! Your solution works great. It gives 4 times faster querries when all tables are concatenated into a single huge one (on a slower server!) versus the original thousands of smaller individual non indexed tables (on a more powerful server). I accept your answer.