# Oracle - single-row subquery returns more than one row , Need to fetch all the rows

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query returns

> "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

```
 select * from  sampleTable
             where 
             status = 'A' 
             and (SELECT SUBSTR(some_code_column, 1, 4) from sampleTable) = 9999
```

I need to fetch all the rows of the table where status is A and All the rows with `SUBSTR(some_code_column, 1, 4) = 9999`
How to change the query so that it fetches the required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for that sub-select, simply AND the conditions:

```
select * from  sampleTable
             where 
             status = 'A' 
             and SUBSTR(some_code_column, 1, 4)  = 9999
```

Comment: Actually AND instead of OR worked for me.  SUBSTR(some_code_column, 1, 4)  = 9999 is perfectly fine. I wonder what was wrong with my head and I was making it complicated with sub query and all. Anyways, thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

*This was before you clarified you wanted to return data that satisfies both conditions not one or the other*.

I would use a `UNION` in this scenario.

```
SELECT *
FROM sampleTable
WHERE status = 'A'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM sampleTable
WHERE SUBSTR(some_code_column, 1, 4)  = 9999
```

More reading on performance here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866221/2641576

Answer (score 0):

You want both the conditions to get true or any of them??  In case any of them then please use `OR` instead of `AND`