# Union Query with Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I need to check if a record exists or not in php zend.

I have the following `sql` query which works fine and gives the proper results

```
(SELECT * FROM email where isLogged = 1 and emailId='demo@xyz.com') 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM email where idPeople = 5 and emailId='demo@xyz.com');
```

I want to write this query using `Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists` to check if record with `email= 'demo@xyz.com'` exists or not under said conditions.

Comment: Please keep in mind that ZF and ZF2 are different thins in many ways.

Comment: Clear up the question.

Comment: @ShawnMehan I want the `union` query to execute using `Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists ` api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would use a UNION for this, the following code should do the job:

```
$email     = 'demo@xyz.com';
$clause    = $dbAdapter->quoteIdentifier('isLogged') . ' != 1 OR ' . $dbAdapter->quoteIdentifier('idPeople') . ' != 5';
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists(
    array(
        'table'   => 'email',
        'field'   => 'emailId',
        'adapter' => $dbAdapter,
        'exclude' => $clause
    )
);

if ($validator->isValid($email)) {
    // username appears to be valid
} else {
    // username is invalid; print the reason
    $messages = $validator->getMessages();
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo "$message\n";
    }
}
```

The code excludes records that either have `isLogged != 1` or `idPeople != 5`, please let me know if I misunderstood.

**Edit:** I got curious about UNION vs OR performance and found this link explaining some of the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866221/3784145

Comment: Can you formulate the query from your answer? I will check the results.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM email where (isLogged = 1 OR idPeople = 5) and emailId='demo@xyz.com'`