# Optimize MySQL Query ti may it faster

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to MySQL and would like to ask how can you fine tune this query or rewrite it in a better way.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM emp
 WHERE birth_date BETWEEN '1999-05-01'
 AND '1999-05-31'
 OR last_name in ('Bart', 'Martha', 'Lisa');
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Can you also explain why you did it so I would know

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is the query taking too long for the execution?

Comment: Hi Milan, Sorry I was not able to clarify that. Yes it is taking time to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question [SQL Performance UNION vs OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750475/sql-performance-union-vs-or)  is what you are looking for 
the first answer explains the difference between OR and UNION and in your case this might be the best optimization.

Comment: Thanks Bozhidar I will check this now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) command to get more insight about your query and how you can optimize it.

Comment: Thanks Liron, I am still learning the MYSQL and EXPLAIN seems to be a good help in this journey