# Mysql query to find records on defined file_type and their Project type and Parent Id

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL database whose structure is somewhat like

```
id |parent_id| project_id | name | file_type
-------------------------------------------
1  |  NULL   |    p1      | abc1  |    f1
2  |  NULL   |    p1      | abc2  |    f2
3  |  1      |    p1      | abc3  |    f2
4  |  NULL   |    p2      | abc4  |    f1
5  |  1      |    p1      | abc5  |    f3
6  |  NULL   |    p2      | abc6  |    f3
7  |  4      |    p2      | abc7  |    f1
8  |  NULL   |    p1      | abc8  |    f2
9  |  7      |    p2      | abc9  |    f1
```

I am trying to fetch all records whose **parent_id** must be NULL and **project_id** must be 'p1' and **file_type** can be either 'f1' or 'f2'

As per my current progress this query is working for me

> SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE (project_id = 'p1' AND parent_id Is NULL
>   AND file_type='f1') OR (project_id = 'p1' AND parent_id Is NULL AND
>   file_type='f2');

Is there some better way to fetch the required records like using joins?
The approach with high performance is preferable.

Also since I am using file_type to filter out records.

> So adding an index on file_type column will be good or not?

Datatype of this column is Varchar(50)

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this (there is absolutely no need to use joins):

```
SELECT * FROM testtable 
WHERE project_id = 'p1' AND parent_id Is NULL AND file_type IN ('f1','f2') ;
```

Comment: Is 'IN' the right way to work with table having million of records?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    testtable 
WHERE
    parent_id IS NULL
    AND project_id = 'p1'
    AND file_type IN ('f1','f2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE project_id = 'p1' AND parent_id is NULL AND file_type in ('f1', 'f2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create composite index on `project_id` and `file_type`. Use `UNION` to optimize the response time.

```
SELECT * FROM testtable 
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    AND project_id = 'p1'
    AND file_type = 'f1'
UNION
SELECT * FROM testtable 
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    AND project_id = 'p1'
    AND file_type = 'f2'
```

Purpose of `Index` is violated in case of `OR` clauses. Splitting the queries and merging it's results using `UNION` will definitely make complete use of indexing.

Comment: As given  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866221/3085520) on SO UNION is preferred while using OR on different columns. I am filtering out results from single column. Did UNION still makes sense?

Comment: Yes it does. It's my personal experience. Try it out :)