# MySql Select columns from same table based on different condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have to run multiple selects on a table for and get resultset for 2 columns. One solution i found is by using **UNION** as below.

```
SELECT cap_id, cap_code FROM cap_master
where cap_type = 'Type1' and cap_desc = 'CapDesc1' 
 UNION
SELECT cap_id, cap_code FROM cap_master
where cap_type = 'Type2' and cap_desc = 'CapDesc2'
```

Is there any other way to do this. There could be some 10-20 select statements in one go. Will this affect performance, if so what would be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just be able to use one query with a larger `WHERE` clause using `OR` statements.

Example

```
SELECT cap_id, cap_code
FROM cap_master
WHERE (cap_type = 'Type1' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc1`) 
    OR (cap_type = 'Type2' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc2')
```

That is a least a starting point for getting results for only when the `cap_type` and `cap_desc` are specific values.

Comment: Thanks Dan!! This will reduce my query a lot. Any idea, will this cause any performance overhead if have have 10-20 conditions ? If yes, what is the better approach?

Comment: I don't know your use case, but it would seem having those conditions means you aren't using your query in the right place within your solution. I can't speak to a better approach there. I do know `UNION` will try to sort through duplicates, which you shouldn't have. There is another question that digs into performance between the two query options that you can view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750475/sql-performance-union-vs-or). From my experience, `OR` statements tend to work better than multiple result-sets using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`