# How to achieve CTE functionality in MySQL 5 .7?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, inner-join, common-table-expression

I have a USERSEARCH table that should be used for fast substring searches for users. This feature is for an autocomplete search that occurs while someone is typing in a username or name. However, the query I am interested in will only show matches from users the subset of users the searcher follows. This is found in the USERRELATIONSHIP table.

```
USERSEARCH
-----------------------------------------------
user_id(FK)    username_ngram          name_ngram
1              "AleBoy leBoy eBoy..."  "Ale le e"
2              "craze123 raze123 ..."  "Craze raze aze ze e"
3              "john1990 ohn1990 ..."  "John ohn hn n"
4              "JJ_1 J_1 _1 1"         "JJ"


USERRELATIONSHIP
-----------------------------------------------
user_id(FK)    follows_id(FK)
2              1
2              3
```

A query like this would be made when someone has just typed in "Al" (not accounting for user relationships):

```
SELECT * FROM myapp.usersearch where username_ngram like 'Al%'
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT * FROM myapp.usersearch where name_ngram like 'Al%'
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT * FROM myapp.usersearch                            
        WHERE MATCH (username_ngram, name_ngram) AGAINST ('Al')  
        LIMIT 10
```

This is blazingly fast because of the existing indices on username_ngram, name_ngram and FULLTEXT(username_ngram, name_ngram). However, in my application context, I need to restrict the search to users that the searcher is following. I would like to replace the "myapp.usersearch" table with a subset of the "myapp.usersearch" table including only users the searcher is following. Here is what I attempted:

```
    WITH

--Part 1, restrict the USERSEARCH table to just the users that are followed by searcher

        tempUserSearch AS (SELECT T1.id, T2.username_ngram, T2.name_ngram FROM
        (SELECT follows_id FROM myapp.userrelationship WHERE user_id = {user_idOfSearcher} ) AS T1 
        LEFT JOIN myapp.usersearch AS T2  ON T2.user_id = T1.follows_id)

            SELECT * FROM tempUserSearch where username_ngram like 'Al%'
            UNION DISTINCT
            SELECT * FROM tempUserSearch where name_ngram like 'Al%'
            UNION DISTINCT
            SELECT * FROM tempUserSearch                            
            WHERE MATCH (username_ngram, name_ngram) AGAINST ('Al')  
            LIMIT 10
```

Unfortunately MySQL 5.7 does not support the CTE WITH clause.

**Is there any way to reference part 1 of the query in all subsequent subqueries without re-requerying the user_ids of the users the person follows? (in MySQL 5.7)**

Update:

Is there really no way to reference a query multiple times in MySQL 5.7? Something seems off as this appears to me as a fundamental task for any db.

Why not do : "x join y on a or b or c"? The speed of my substring query depends on the following indices:

```
index(username_ngram)

index(name_ngram)

FULLTEXT(username_ngram, name_ngram)
```

And using OR is not helped by any indices.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Don’t use MySQL for this kind of search. Use use a text based nosql DB like lucene or elastic search etc, and add to each user a “followed by” field and search using that and the partial name.

Comment: Have you compared to x join y on a or b or c? PS Learn the basics of relational & SQL optimization/implementation by query engines in general via textbooks & the web & SO & in particular via DBMS manual--all immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. Appropriate research is expected for questions. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS That comment is too terse to understand. PS How were you not helped by googling (say) 'alternatives to CTE in MySQL site:stackoverflow.com' or 'reuse subquery in MySQL site:stackoverflow.com'? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: @philipxy I have for the past two hours.

Comment: Your boldface question "reference a query multiple times in MySQL 5.7" is a faq & the answers are no & alternatives are given. But--Google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of a question/problem/goal, with & without  site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. (See 2 above.) If you want options on your specific code, give all relevant details. You don't summarize much optimization & subquery research & testing. Still no [mre], including indexes or EXPLAINs. Or how you are constrained in querying or other DML like temporaries, which apparently, from your comments, you are. Etc.

Answer (score 6):

MySQL 5.7 does not support common table expression; the `WITH` syntax is available in version 8.0 only.

Since your existing query runs fast, filtering in an outer query might be viable solution:

```
SELECT ur.id, ng.username_ngram, ng.name_ngram
FROM myapp.userrelationship ur
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM myapp.usersearch WHERE username_ngram LIKE 'Al%'
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT * FROM myapp.usersearch WHERE name_ngram LIKE 'Al}%'
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT * FROM myapp.usersearch WHERE MATCH (username_ngram, name_ngram) AGAINST ('Al')  
) ng ON ng.user_id = ur.follows_id
WHERE ur.user_id = {user_idOfSearcher}
ORDER BY ??
LIMIT 10
```

Notes:

- I turned `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` because I think that's closer to what you want (you can change it back if it doesn't fit you requirement)
- You need an `ORDER BY` clause to go along with the `LIMIT`, otherwise the results are not deterministic when there are more that 10 rows in the resultset

Comment: You are right to be suspicious, I just updated the question please take a look. Id in (2,3) was a simplification for the user_ids that the searcher follows, this actually takes a subquery on the USERRELATIONSHIP table. I do not necessarily need the LIMIT 10 to be deterministic, does leaving out the ORDER BY speed things up?

Comment: @Rage: now it makes more sense (although the joining columns in your query are not aligned with those you select). I updated my answer. Leaving the `ORDER BY` apart *might* speed up the query, depending on other factors such as how many rows the query returns (before `LIMIT` is applied). You would need to assess that against your actual data.

Comment: Thank you for the revision but I am not sure I understand your query. Could you please add some comments for clarification? Just to refresh what we are trying to do: Query the USERRELATIONSHIP table to get all the user_ids that the searcher is following. Then left join those follows_ids on the USERSEARCH table which reduces its size greatly. Only then do we search for string matches. I believe your query first searches the USERSEARCH table for all matches regardless of relationship and then subsequently filters the result, this seems potentially unnecessarily expensive to me. Thoughts?

Comment: @Rage: your understanding is correct. Why I suggested that is explained in my answer...  *Since your existing query runs fast, filtering in an outer query might be viable solution*

Comment: I see. Just because the internal query runs fast does not mean we can afford a slow outer query. Since the application context is autocomplete and depends on performance I would rather stay away from an outer filter. Do you have any other ideas? Perhaps there is a way to mimic CTE from newer SQL versions where tempUserSearch does not have to be re-queried each time?

Comment: @Rage: (1) if the inner query runs fast, so will probably the whole query probably - test it before you drop it (2) upgrade to MySQL 8.0 (with supports CTEs), or repeat the join filtering in each of the `unioned` queries (but it's not guaranteed to be faster).

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading to MySQL is not possible because my database is hosted on Google Cloud SQL which currently only supports MySQL 5.7. Before I consider the performance differences between your query and repeating the join filtering in each unioned query I must ask again: Is there really no way to reference a query multiple times in MySQL 5.7? Something seems off as this appears to me as a fundamental task for any db.

Comment: @Rage: *Is there really no way to reference a query multiple times in MySQL 5.7?* No, none that I know about.