# Index for OR query where value is the same on both columns

Tags: mysql

I have following use case:

My table (significant parts):

```
CREATE TABLE transfers (
    id int,
    product_id int,
    source_location_id int,
    destination_location_id int,
    quantity int,
    created_at datetime
);
```

Now my query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM transfers 
WHERE (source_location_id = 123 OR destination_location_id = 123)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 400
```

At the moment that table contains 20 million rows and this query takes 2-3 minutes to finish)

Is there a way to create an index for that `OR` clause since this specific `id` will always be the same for both locations in that SELECT.

I have seen some people mentioning unions for OR clause, but I am using an ORM that does not support `UNIONS` nor `SUBQUERIES`, plus unions will not work with pagination.

Comment: AFAIK creating an index for both columns should fix your problem. Have you tried that? i.e. add `INDEX source_destination_location_Id (source_location_id, destination_location_id)` to your `CREATE TABLE` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: No, a multi-column index will not help. I wrote an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750475/sql-performance-union-vs-or/13866221#13866221

Comment: If you are using an ORM that doesn't allow UNION or subquery, then I'm afraid you can't optimize this query while using the ORM methods.  You will have to abandon use of the ORM and write the SQL directly, at least for this specific query. That should be ordinary use of any ORM — use the object methods for simple, repetitive queries, and use SQL directly for queries the ORM doesn't support well.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no index that will help this.  To have this query indexed, you need a union, optimally like:

```
SELECT transfers.* 
FROM transfers 
JOIN (
    (
        SELECT id, created_at
        FROM transfers 
        WHERE source_location_id = 123
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
        LIMIT 500
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (
        SELECT id, created_at
        FROM transfers 
        WHERE destination_location_id = 123
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
        LIMIT 500
    )
) ids USING (id)
ORDER BY ids.created_at DESC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 400
```

If source and destination are never the same, UNION ALL should be used instead.

Alternatively, add another table like:

```
CREATE transfer_locations (
    transfer_id int,
    location_id int,
    created_at datetime,
    primary key (location_id, transfer_id)
)
```

with rows for the source and destination for each transfer, and select from that, joining transfers.

Comment: the `DISTINCT` should go, and some `()` are needed, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZGTStOAh    And I am not sure about the index `transfer_locations`

Comment: @Luuk no, if source and destination are the same, DISTINCT is required.  thanks for catching the parens issue

Comment: oh, you want just UNION instead of UNION DISTINCT, which defaults to UNION DISTINCT.  I prefer to always have it show

Comment: The DISTINCT is not mandatory, and I always leave it out. (I cannot find the docs that it can be left way .... )

Comment: you almost always should do UNION ALL, so I prefer to call out the few times DISTINCT is actually needed by leaving it in.  re docs, "By default, duplicate rows are removed from results of set operations. The optional DISTINCT keyword has the same effect but makes it explicit" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-operations.html#set-operations-distinct-all