# Is there any alternative way of Q object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Anyone can tell me, have any alternative way of doing it? I actually searched for a more optimized way than it.

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(Q(email="") | Q(phone="")).order_by("name")
```

***phone and email fields are:***

```
phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice to try a "[UNION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#union)".

```py
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs1 = self.queryset.filter(email="")
        qs2 = self.queryset.filter(phone ="")
        return qs1.union(qs2).order_by("name")
```

In some cases, it seems that **UNION** can be more optimized than **OR**.

You have a [very good question about this in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750475/sql-performance-union-vs-or)

Comment: thank you. Btw i would like to know more, are there any more Options present?