# mysql AND morethan one time for a column

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM mark_mapping 
WHERE subcat_id = 22 AND subcat_id = 30 AND subcat_id = 17 AND subcat_id = 18 AND subcat_id = 19
```

This is my sample query. As you know.. this is not working. Help me please.

Here subcat_id may can repeat more than 10 times. All are same columns.

I would like to metion my table structure here....

group_id subcat_id

12 ------->  7 
12 ------->  8  
12 ------->  9 
12 -------> 10 
13 ------->  7 
13 -------> 11 
14 -------> 8 
14 -------> 9

so on.. So what is the correct to get this result...

SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM mark_mapping 
    WHERE subcat_id = 22 AND subcat_id = 30 AND subcat_id = 17 AND subcat_id = 18 AND subcat_id = 19

SELECT group_id 
FROM mark_mapping 
WHERE subcat_id in (22,30,17,18,19)
group by group_id 
having count(distinct subcat_id) = 5

I know that the AND statement is looking for different column. Can any one tell me how can I use it for a column...

Comment: this will newer give you anything. How can subcat_id be 22 AND same time 30?

Comment: wouldn't it be better with OR ?

Comment: or:s are evil = really slow.

Comment: IN is taking all the group_id's.. its like OR operator..I need AND operator for a column

Comment: @Hardy `OR` or `IN` is the solution. You cannot have a row which constains one column twice or more

Comment: @RoyalBg Really? what about UNION. I had this one project where was used "OR" and changing code to use UNION made SQL 10000 faster.

Comment: Thank you all.. for the response.. still I am working on it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT group_id 
FROM mark_mapping 
WHERE subcat_id in (22,30,17,18,19)
group by group_id 
having count(distinct subcat_id) = 5
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeba03/2)

Comment: I thought of same but he written AND in between

Comment: Never! use OR.. it is really really really slow. Trust me i know! Use UNION instead

Comment: @Hardy are you serious?

Comment: KIndly note I am looking AND operation.. Is it possible with the table structure...

Comment: I have benchmarked that! Try by your self UNION is lot faster than OR. At least in MySql databases.

Comment: @AnishCharles, nt, it's not possible. If you have a row which contains `bla_id = 20` and `foo_id = 30` and you tell it: `SELECT theRow FROM tbl WHERE bla_id = 20 AND foo_id = 30` it will work, because for a single row both match. But they cannot match, if you give it `WHERE bla_id = 20 AND bla_id = 30` because bla_id cannot be in one row more than one value. You will need more columns. It will not be normalized table structure, but you will need subcat_id1, subcat_id2, etc...

Comment: @juergend All i have to say: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639710/union-all-vs-or-condition-in-sql-server-query

Comment: @Hardy: Totally not comparable to this question. But you are welcome to set up a SQLFiddle and output the execution plans to prove me wrong.

Comment: @Royal BG -> I can't do that.. because subcat_id is a variable.. it can be many....

Comment: @AnishCharles I think juergen's solution for grouping will be ok?

Comment: Guys... I know that the AND statement is looking for different column. Can any one tell me how can I use it for a column...

Comment: juergen d:-> I hope the solution is correct.. but little slow.. I can make it working.. thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

The query is against a row. You cannot have one row, where column has 2 or more different values. You need `OR` instead of `AND` or better `IN(...)`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM mark_mapping 
WHERE subcat_id IN (22, 30, 17, 18, 19);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong operator.

If you combine conditions using `AND`, rows will only be matched if they meet all requirements. In this case, that's impossible. Each row can only have a single `subcat_id`, so there can't be a row who's `subcat_id` is `22`, `30`, `17`, `18` *AND* `19` at the same time.

You should use the `OR` operator instead:

```
WHERE subcat_id = 22 OR subcat_id = 30 OR subcat_id = 17 OR subcat_id = 18 OR subcat_id = 19
```

Which, translated to plain English, says:

> Give me all rows where the subcat_id is either 22, 30, 17, 18 *OR* 19.

In this case you can also simplify your query by using `IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_id
FROM mark_mapping 
WHERE subcat_id IN (22, 30, 17, 18, 19)
```

This basically looks for rows where `subcat_id` exists *IN* the provided list of values.