# Why Crossjoin is less efficient that union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query that works fast:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER FROM (
SELECT CUSTOMER FROM
EMAILS INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS 
ON EMAILS.email=CUSTOMERS.email1
UNION
SELECT CUSTOMER FROM
EMAILS INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS 
ON EMAILS.email=CUSTOMERS.email2)
```

But cross join is taking forewer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER FROM
EMAILS INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS 
ON EMAILS.email=CUSTOMERS.email1
OR EMAILS.email=CUSTOMERS.email2
-- alternative: EMAILS.email in (CUSTOMERS.email1,CUSTOMERS.email2)
```

Comment: you are performing a `inner join`. not a `cross join`?

Comment: I don't think you need `DISTINCT` in first query `Union` will remove the duplicates

Comment: Difficult to guess without an idea of what your table definitions, data volumes, data distributions, indexes, query execution plans, or Oracle version are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already so many discussion are present about `OR` vs `Union` you can check here

- [UNION ALL vs OR condition in sql server query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639710/union-all-vs-or-condition-in-sql-server-query)
- [SQL Performance UNION vs OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750475/sql-performance-union-vs-or)
- http://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/using-union-instead-of-or

Since you are comparing one column with two different column you can also try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER 
FROM EMAILS 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS 
ON EMAILS.email in (CUSTOMERS.email1,CUSTOMERS.email2)
```

Also you don't need `DISTINCT` in first query `Union` will remove the duplicates