# Combine two select queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have 2 Select Queries

```
select Amount,
       CurrentBalanceCurrency,
       AmountType
from UserBalance
where AmountType= 10

select Amount,
       CurrentBalanceCurrency,
       AmountType
from UserBalance
where AmountType= 20
```

I want to make this query in one line, without hitting my database twice.

Comment: Did you try searching at all? I suggest looking up the syntax for [IN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: `AmountType IN (10,20)` is a shortcut for `(AmountType = 10 or AmountType = 20)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `IN` operator in `where` clause:

```
select Amount, CurrentBalanceCurrency, AmountType 
from UserBalance 
where AmountType in (10,20);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`IN`** operator.

**Query**

```
select [Amount], [CurrentBalanceCurrency], [AmountType]
from [UserBalance]
where [AmountType] in (10,20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use OR between those two conditions:

```
select Amount
,CurrentBalanceCurrency
,AmountType 
from UserBalance where AmountType= 10 OR AmountType = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use **union all** to concatenate the result-sets, this can improve performance over **or** or **in** in some cases (you would have to test for yourself):

```
select Amount,
       CurrentBalanceCurrency,
       AmountType
from UserBalance
where AmountType= 10
union all
select Amount,
       CurrentBalanceCurrency,
       AmountType
from UserBalance
where AmountType= 20
```

Comment: Can the person who downvoted this answer provide some feedback as to why?

Comment: I didn't down vote - I don't disagree with the down vote, although I would not have down voted it, as this answer will return the correct result. You have 2 selects instead of 1 which is unnecessary. The 2 selects will have a worse execution plan than the other answers for this.

Comment: I am not down voter. But I have question. That, How many times this query hits the DB..?

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish this query hits the database once. Just different execution plan

Comment: I did not have knowledge about the execution plan..But Okay.. question 2). `this can improve performance` on which basis...? I want try my self.

Comment: If you have two **or** conditions in your where clause, sometimes the optimiser can choose to do a scan instead of a seek, using **union all** can cause the plan to use two seeks instead.  That's why I used the words "Another option" in my answer, there are many ways to write a query like this.  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639710/union-all-vs-or-condition-in-sql-server-query

Comment: @MJH, that link is hard to understand..Although I keep in mind. Thx